# Can the given expression be simplified? If yes, How?

Tags: summation, permutations, factorial

For any even number $2n$, can the expression $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot (2n-1-k)!$ be simplified to $\dfrac{(2n)!} n \text{?}$

If Yes, then how? If No then what can it be simplified to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hockey stick identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n-1-k}{n-1} = \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Your result follows with a little rearrangement.

Comment: Thank you for helping out!!